# How to change the text color. Simple?

Tags: vb.net

```
If CDbl(totalAverage) >= 89 Then
            lblGrade.Text = "A"
        ElseIf CDbl(totalAverage) >= 79 Then
            lblGrade.Text = "B"
        ElseIf CDbl(totalAverage) >= 69 Then
            lblGrade.Text = "C"
        ElseIf CDbl(totalAverage) >= 59 Then
            lblGrade.Text = "D"
        ElseIf CDbl(totalAverage) >= 0 Then
            lblGrade.Text = "F"
        End If
```

Just trying to change the colors of the text to green for an A, B, or C.  Orange for a D, and red for an F.

I was thinking it was lblGrade.Text.Color or something like that; however, that didn't seem to be a command and I've been looking around and was having trouble finding the answer to this and thought it would be easier to just ask here.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lblGrade.Forecolor is what your looking for.

For orange, it would be "lblGrade.ForeColor = Color.Orange"

Comment: I knew it was a easy command but im a newbie at this stuff.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know about that.  Will do in the future also.